# regarding using **kwargs to pass the parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am reading the following code segment, this function was once invoked as `generator = image_gen.get_image_gen_rgb(nx, ny, cnt=20)`.  I am not very clear about the usage of `**kwargs` in the function of `get_image_gen_rgb`. Does `cnt=20` was used to setup the parameter of `n_image` in `create_batch`

```
def get_image_gen_rgb(nx, ny, **kwargs):
    def create_batch(n_image):
        print("n_image: ",n_image)
        X = np.zeros((n_image, nx, ny, 3))
        Y = np.zeros((n_image, nx, ny,2))

        for i in range(n_image):
            x, Y[i,:,:,1] = create_image_and_label(nx,ny, **kwargs)
            X[i] = to_rgb(x)
            Y[i,:,:,0] = 1-Y[i,:,:,1]

        return X, Y
  create_batch.channels = 3
  create_batch.n_class = 2
  return create_batch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cnt=20` was used for the derivation of `x` and second slice of the last axis of `Y` via `create_image_and_label`:

```
x, Y[i,:,:,1] = create_image_and_label(nx,ny, **kwargs) # kwargs = {'cnt': 20}
```

Comment: Hi Moses,  in the context of this code segment, which one is used to setup n_image. I added a print out function, and found n_image = 19. But the way, what do you mean the second slice of the last axis of Y? Thanks

Comment: `n_image` is not setup in that code. You're returning the function `create_batch` which when called, `n_image` is passed; you should loop up closures in Python. First slice of last axis: `Y[i,:,:,0]` and second slice `Y[i,:,:,1]`; a numpy thing

Comment: Thanks for the reply. if n_image is not setup, where does it come from? I added a print function in the original code, and found that it keeps output 19. But I just could not find where does it come from.

Comment: That function will be called as `image_gen.get_image_gen_rgb(nx, ny, cnt=20)(19)`. Have a look at closures in Python